# Chart.js is not showing charts on IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, chart.js

I am working on an admin panel. I converted it from PSD to HTML. I used chart.js for charts. It works fine on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE 11. But on IE 10 or lower  chart.js is not showing any kind of chart. I tried to fix this and spend lot of time. But i can't. I added excanvas js. but it didn't work.

Here is one of my Doughnut chart code -

```
<div id="canvas-holder">
    <canvas id="chart-area4" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
    <div class="donut-inner4 cycle_top">
       <h5>12</h5>
       <span>ERRORS</span>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  doughnutData4 = [
            {
                value: 60,
                color:"#F68337",
                highlight: "#F68337",
            },
            {
                value: 40,
                color: "#D6D9DB",
                highlight: "#D6D9DB",
            },

        ];

    var ctx11 = document.getElementById("chart-area4").getContext("2d");
            window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx11).Doughnut(doughnutData4,{
            responsive : true,
            segmentShowStroke : false,
            percentageInnerCutout: 80});

</script>
```

Here is the link - http://demo.devkinz.com/adminpanel

Can anyone give me the solution?

Comment: I have tested your demo on IE > 8 (emulation) and worked properly.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like trailing commas in the array literal?

Comment: Trailing commas in objects and arrays crashes all versions of IE. The only solution is to write clean javascript.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable comment. But i still can't solve it. Can you please suggest me a code.
Thanks.